# Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Tags: java

I download the Gurobi package for linear programming. I import the corresponding gurobi.jar package. Then run the example program. Then it appears the following errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\gurobi460\win64\win64\bin\GurobiJni46.dll: **Can't load AMD 64-bit
>   .dll on a IA 32-bit platform**

Then I downloaded the window 64 bit Jre, and use the "window-->preference-->Installed JRE" to install this new JRE.

However, it still appeared this error.

Comment: what kind/version of windows are you using?

Answer (score 22):

If you are still getting that error after installing the 64 bit JRE, it means that the JVM running Gurobi package is still **using** the 32 bit JRE.

Check that you have updated the PATH and JAVA_HOME globally and in the command shell that you are using.  (Maybe you just need to exit and restart it.)

Check that your command shell runs the right version of Java by running "java -version" and checking that it says it is a 64bit JRE.

If you are launching the example via a wrapper script / batch file, make sure that the script is using the right JRE.  Modify as required ...

If you are launching the example via an IDE, check that the IDE is using the right JRE to launch.  Check and modify the IDE configs.  The details will depend on the IDE you are using.  Check the documentation.  (Just setting external environment variables such as `JAVA_HOME` *may not be sufficient* in this case.)

Comment: If I use the eclipse to run my program, do I still need to set the PATH and classpath? JAVA_HOME is for the JDK. Now I choose JDK 1.6 in the eclipse for the compiler. How do I set it? I just install the JRE windows 64 bit.

Comment: I get it. I need to also set the "run configuration" 's JRE in the eclipse.

Comment: Yes.  (You didn't mention you were using Eclipse in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Download and install a 32-bit JDK.
2. Go to eclipse click on your project (Run As → Run Configurations...) under Java Application branch.
3. Go to the JRE tab and select Alternate JRE. Click on Installed JRE button, add your 32-bit JRE and select.

Comment: I think you have got it wrong. The error message is saying that Gurobi is loading a 64 bit DLL, but the platform is 32-bit. If you download, install, configure and use a 32-bit JDK to run Gurobi, then the platform is **still 32-bit**. Same problem as before.  The DLL still won't load.

Answer (score -6):

Uninstall(delete) this: jre, jdk, eclipse.
Download 32 bit(x86) version of this programs:jre, jdk, eclipse.
And install it.