# LWJGL Error with Native Libraries

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm trying to run the physiball project from [Phys2D](https://code.google.com/p/phys2d/) but when I build it and run it with the path to the LWJGL natives (which I had to download), I get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` with the description `Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform` I'm running windows Vista 32-bit and I've tried googling this problem finding only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167062/cant-load-amd-64-bit-dll-on-a-ia-32-bit-platform) result, which is someone on a 64-bit operating system. I'm running a 32-bit operating system but it seems to be trying to use the 64-bit natives. How can I fix this?

edit: My processor is 64-bit, but I'm running a 32-bit operating system.

Comment: More infos for *which* library this message appears? Do you use the 32bit-versions of the LWJGL DLL? (It should figure this out, I'm just asking...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the project is really old so it uses a really old version of LWJGL, and the ones from LWJGL 3 weren't working. Using the natives from LWJGL 1.1.4 fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

download [this](http://build.lwjgl.org/release/latest/lwjgl.zip), there are all natives, you need to link them in eclipse... there are many tutorials for that, maybe youtube can help you with "installing lwjgl"

the natives default directory will be in the root directory of your .jar file

i hope that helps you fixing your linker error

Comment: That's the exact file that I downloaded and I used VM arguments in netbeans to point to the natives. The problem is not me not having the natives.

Comment: do you finaly got the natives for lwjgl1.1.4?
may, if you have the sources, you could open the project and use lwjgl 2.* or 3.* and fix the shown errors... i think 1.1.4 is to old to find the natives for it anywhere... your last chance is maybe to find the natives in the gitProjects of lwjgl or this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%201.1.4/lwjgl-1.1.4.zip/download

Comment: I already have the 1.1.4 natives and got it running. Thanks though :D